# Pyside setText() not updating QLabel

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have the following:

```
 self.testTxt = QtGui.QLabel("0")
 .
 .
 for i in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        self.testTxt.setText(unicode(i))
```

but the QLabel doesn't get updated till the end of the loop

I've tried:

```
self.processEvents()
self.testTxt.update()
```

But to no avail.

Does anyone happen to know why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use QThread.  I'll try and write an example a little later if no one else does.

Comment: ..or, a bit simpler, a QTimer.

Comment: If I use a Qtimer to an outside function the Qtimer no longer updates once I'm in the main loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text box does not update because the program is tied up inside the for loop and thus never gets back to Qt's event loop to redraw the widget. Calling testTxt.update() does not help because, as the [QWidget documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update) states, update() simply *schedules* a repaint for the next time the event loop is run (and this is taken care of when you call setText anyway).

Possible solutions:

- Use QTimer to make repeated calls to a function that updates the text (this is the preferred solution)
- call testText.repaint() after every call to setText
- call QApplication.processEvents() after every call to setText

Comment: If I use a Qtimer to an outside function the Qtimer no longer updates once I'm in the main loop...

Comment: Correct, for exactly the same reason--the Qt event loop is responsible for driving the QTimer, and that can not happen until your function exits. So the idea is that your function should _only_ update the label once (it should _not_ make multiple updates or have a call to sleep). Instead use the QTimer to invoke your single-update function once per second. If this is still confusing, you should read about QTimer and look up some examples of how it is used.