# PySide and Qt Properties: Connecting signals from Python to QML

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am trying to run a simple PySide appliccation with design made in QML. I would like to call function in QML from Python in a separated thread.

**I have following QML view:**

```
import Qt 4.7

Rectangle {
    visible: true

    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "lightgrey"

    Text {
        id: dateStr
        objectName: "dateStr"
        x: 10
        y: 10
        text: "Init text"
        font.pixelSize: 12

        function updateData(text) {
            dateStr.text = qsTr(text)
            console.log("You said: " + text)
        }

    }

}
```

**Here is my application:**

Some imports....

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time

from PySide import QtDeclarative, QtCore 
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtDeclarative import QDeclarativeView
```

The QThread Worker....

```
#Worker thread
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):

    updateProgress = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, child):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.child = child

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            #Call the function updateData - DOES NOT WORK
            self.child.updateData("Other string ")
```

and here is the view assembled:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create the view
    view = QDeclarativeView()
    # Connect it with QML
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('main_ui.qml'))
    # Show UI
    view.show()

    #Get the root object and find the child dateStr
    root = view.rootObject()
    child = root.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "dateStr")

    #Call the function updateData - THIS WORKS
    child.updateData("String")

    worker = Worker(child)
    worker.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If the QML function `updateData(text)` is called from Qthread, the `dateStr.text` is not set but the console message is produced. If the QML function is called from within main function, the update of `dateStr.text` works normally.

**Question**

How is the proper way to call QML function from QtThread?

**Links**

[PySide tutorial: Connecting signals from Python to QML](https://wiki.qt.io/Connecting_QML_Signals_in_PySide#Connecting_signals_from_Python_to_QML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in other thread:

[StackOverflow: Pyside setText() not updating QLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836623/pyside-settext-not-updating-qlabel)

In this case the widget is not repainted and therefore it is needed to force the application to repaint it. I used this code (see [PySide Docs: QApplication](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QApplication.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QApplication.allWidgets)):

```
def updateAllWidgets():
    for widget in QApplication.allWidgets():
        widget.update()
```

This function can be called for example by the timer:

```
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.start(1000)
timer.timeout.connect(updateAllWidgets)
```

See also:
[PySide: Calling a Python function from QML and vice versa](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyside/NDLYxD5WGVQ)